# Scala Akka Actors: How to send the result of an Http response back to the sender?

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-actor

I'm trying to execute the following Scala code inside an Akka Actor.

```
class FilteringService(implicit timeout: Timeout) extends Actor {

  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {

    case GetProfiles ⇒
      val requester = sender
      def getProfiles = {

        var result = new Array[Profile](0)

        println("[GET-PROFILES] Entered, making request")
        val req = Get("http://localhost:9090/profiles")
        implicit val profileFormat = jsonFormat16(Profile)


        val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(req)
        println("[GET-PROFILES] Entered, request sent")
        responseFuture.onComplete {

          case Success(response) =>
            println("[RES - SUCCESS] Request returned with " + response.status)
            val responseAsProfiles =  Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Array[Profile]]
            responseAsProfiles.onComplete {
            println("[UNMARSH - SUCCESS] Unmarshaling Done!")
            _.get match {
              case profiles: Array[Profile] =>
                println("[UNMARSH - SUCCESS] Sending Profiles message to " + sender())
                requester ! profiles
                println("[UNMARSH - SUCCESS] Message sent to " + sender())
              case _ => println("error")
              }
            }

          case Failure(_)   =>
            sys.error("something wrong")
            //return Future[Array[Profile]]

        }
      }
      println("[RECEIVE] Message GetProfiles received from " + sender().toString())
      getProfiles
      println("[RECEIVE] Message GetProfiles invoked")

  }
```

When the Actor receives the message "GetProfiles":

1- it sends a request to a remote server, so the result of operation is a Future[HttpResponse]

2- in case of success it retrieves the response (a JSON array) and asks for unmarshalling the object to Array[Profile]. (It's not important the Profile model). The result of Unmarshall method is a Future[Array[Profile]]

3- In case of success, I want to send the result back to the original sender!

I managed to do this, but it's a trick because I'm saving the sender in a variable, that is visible in the scope (**requester**).
I know that there is the pipe pattern, so I could send the **responseAsProfiles** object back to the sender in theory, but the object is created inside the onComplete method of the **responseFuture** object (we have to wait it, of course!)

So that's all!
How could I send the result back to the sender using the pipe pattern in this case?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General idea is that you compose futures using `map` and `flatMap` and try to avoid using `onComplete` as much as possible.

See if you can convert your code to following smaller pieces and then compose:

```scala
def getRawProfileData(): Future[HttpResponse] = {
 // ... here you make http request
}

def unmarshalProfiles(response: HttpResponse): Future[List[Profile]] = {
  // ... unmarshalling logic
}

def getProfiles(): Future[List[Profile]] = getRawProfileData().flatMape(unmarshalProfiles)

// now from receive block

case GetProfiles ⇒ getProfiles().pipeTo(sender())
```

Comment: Great! Thanks to @Pritam! It works fine and I think now it's very clean.